# Numbers of units in the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $$R=\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle.$$ Find the number of units in $R$.

Solution: By definition of factor ring we write $$R=\{ax+b+\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z_3}\}.$$ Here $R$ contain $9$ elements as both $a$ and $b$ have 3 choices.

We can easily verify that the ideal is not prime in the ring, so $R$ is not an integral domain.

Now my **doubt** is when the ideal is not prime in the ring how do we examine the ring writing all the elements and checking one by one certain properties for instant no. of units? or else we have some short trick to solve it.

That is $$R=\mathbb{Z_3[x]/\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle}=\mathbb{Z_3[x]}/\langle x+2 \rangle \langle x+2 \rangle$$
I'm stuck here

please give any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but for this particular problem, you may find the units by solving the equation $(ax+b)(cx+d) = 1$ modulo $x^2+x+1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$R=\mathbb Z_3[x]/\langle(x+2)^2\rangle\cong\mathbb Z_3[y]/\langle y^2\rangle,$ the isomorphism between these two quotients being induced by the isomorphism $\mathbb Z_3[y]\to\mathbb Z_3[x], \;P(y)\mapsto P(x+2).$

In $\mathbb Z_3[y]/\langle y^2\rangle,$ $(ay+b)(cy+d)=(ad+bc)y+bd$ hence $ay+b$ is a unit iff $b\ne0.$ So, there are $6$ units $\pmod{y^2}$: $0y+1,0y+2,1y+1,1y+2,2y+1,2y+2$.

Comment: please can you explain how can we write the isomorphic part and how the elements look for this ring?

Comment: Well, according to your answer then, we need to find number of solutions to `bd ≠ 0' which implies 2 choices of b and d i.e., 1 and 2. and total solutions = 3. (b,d) = {(1,1), (1, 2), (2,1)}

Comment: @VisheshMangla Not 3 but 6 units, precisely according to my answer.  I just edited to make it more explicit.

Comment: Thank you, @AnneBauval. I now understand how you obtained six solutions, but the calculations in the answer may still be incomplete. The actual equation is $(ad+bc) \equiv 0, 1, 2 \pmod{3}$, and $bd \equiv 1,2 \pmod{3}$. I have verified that there is a solution for each of the cases for a and c but I am curious to know in what cases one can omit the verification. It looks like always if I see this.

Comment: @VisheshMangla I don't think the answer is incomplete. It seems that what you are missing is why "ay+b
 is a unit iff b≠0". Given $a,b$ and solving for $c,d$ (elements of $\Bbb Z_3$), "the actual equation is" *not* "ad+bc=0,1,2, and bd=1,2", but $ad+bc=0$ and $bd=1$, hence there is a solution $(c,d)$ iff $b\ne0$, (the solution being then $d=b^{-1},c=-b^{-2}a=-a$, but we don't bother).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @AnneBauval